# why is the text transparent in both the tool tip content and the text of its parent?

Tags: css

I have a tool tip with a class of `.toolTip` and its content has a class of `.toolTipContent`. there are two `spans` in the tooltip The first `span` has the text *"hover here"* and the second is the tooltip *content*.  I selected the first `span` in `.toolTip` for it to be transparent but still it is visible when `.toolTipContent` pops up when `hovering` over it, however both `spans` are transparent

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pwnftkpk/6/)

Code:

```
    .toolTip:hover > span {
         color: rgba(0,0,0,.08);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you use mean all the span under .toolTip will be transparent. If you want to transparent the first element under .toolTip use this

```
.toolTip:hover > span:first-child {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.08);
}
```